# Better way of RxJS Sequence

Tags: angular, sequence, rxjs5

How do I simplify this sequence, as I seem to be re-creating the pyramid of doom, and there ought to be a more Rx-y way.

```
public isEligibleForOffers(): Observable<Boolean> {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
        this.getAccounts().subscribe(
            (accounts) => {
                if (!this.accountsAreInCredit(accounts)) {
                    observer.next(false);
                } else {
                    this.getOffers(accounts).subscribe(
                        (data: Offers) => {
                            let isEligible = (data.eligible && this.eligibleForAny(data) === true && this.registeredForAny(data) !== true);
                            observer.next(isEligible);
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
    });
}
```

I need to make an XHR call to get a collection of accounts, and if the accounts are in credit, make another XHR call to get current offers, and if the user is eligible for any offer return true otherwise false.

Essentially

- Make an initial XHR call
- When you have the result
- Make a 2nd XHR call using the results from the 1st call
- When you have the result
- Make some final decision.

The difference between what I'm asking and what I've seen on SO is twofold:

- These async operations are in sequence and non-overlapping
- The payload from the first response is used in the second

Another similar case might be (1) Get a token, then (2) use the token in a subsequent request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to chain the observables, use `switchMap` or `flatMap`. Also, you do not need to purposely create another Observables using `Observable.create()`, since your `this.getAccounts()` is already returning an observable.

This should be more succinct:

```
public isEligibleForOffers(): Observable<Boolean> {
    return this.getAccounts().switchMap(accounts => {
        if (this.accountsAreInCredit(accounts)) {
            return this.getOffers(accounts)
                .map((data: Offers) => {
                    return (data.eligible && this.eligibleForAny(data) === true && this.registeredForAny(data) !== true);
                })
        }
        //you can be explicit by returning a an Observable of false:
        return Obersvable.of(false);
    })
}
```

And you can just use it like this:

```
this.isEligibleForOffers()
    .subscribe(flag => {
        //flag is a boolean
        if(flag){
            //do something
        }else{
            //do something else
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Given signatures:

```
getAccounts(): Account[]
accountsAreInCredit(accounts: Account[]): boolean
getOffers(accounts: Account[]): Offers
```

You could model your function as follows:

```
public isEligibleForOffers(): Observable<Boolean> {
  return this.getAccounts()
    .filter(accounts => this.accountsAreInCredit(accounts))
    .mergeMap(
      accounts => this.getOffers(accounts),
      (accounts, offers) => offers.eligible && this.eligibleForAny(offers) && !this.registeredForAny(offers))
    )
    .concat(Rx.Observable.of(false))
    .take(1);
  }
```

So if `accountsAreInCredit` yields false the stream will become empty and we then use the `.concat` operator to append a default value of `false` to the stream.

The `mergeMap` (aka `flatMap`) takes an [optional argument `resultSelector`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) in which you can map the output values so we map them to the `isEligibleForOffers` boolean value.

Then finally by limiting the amount of values the function `isEligibleForOffers` can produce we prevent ourselves from emitting `true` (from the `mergeMap`) and `false` (the default from the `concat`) as emissions.

Comment: would accountaAreInCredit not be called multiple times, once per account?

Comment: Given that `getAccounts()` returns an array of `Account` it would be invoked only once with the array. No caching has been applied in above example so if you invoke `isEligibleForOffers()` multiple times all code will be executed multiple times.